# How to send cookies from nodejs local server to another local server like react?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, passport.js

Im using passportjs with nodejs server for my authentication and its work fine when I test it on the same url with postman. but when I used a different local url like react and trying to do a login from there its didnt work. and I found out that the issue was that the server cant send  cookies if the request came from another local url. how can I fix this and test it correctly?

Comment: Have a look at this https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.cookie. I'm assuming you are using express as backend

Comment: I have tried to set the samesite key to"none" and the secure to true but it still didnt work